# .hover and div appearing interfering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a bookmarklet that will upload a image from the page the user is on when it is clicked, all is going well so far but i have hit a bump.

what i want to happen is,

1. User clicks bookmarklet
2. User hovers over an image on the page.
3. a div appears on hover
4. when div is clicked it is taken to my website.

But the div that appears messes with the .hover, it stutters back and forth. I am guessing this is because technically the user isn't hovering over the image anymore rather the div i have created.

Here is a example.
http://jsfiddle.net/P4b8H/

How could i fix this?

Comment: what is the roll of the div tag?

Comment: 4. when div is clicked it is taken to my website.

Comment: why not clicking the image directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're **always leaving** the image, i.e. hovering out, when your div is created. But then in the hover-out function you're hiding the div, so you're kinda stuck in an infinite loop.

To solve, consider having a mouseover *on the image* and a mouseout *on the div*.

```
$("img").mouseover(function(){});

$('#WRAPPER').mouseleave(function() {});
```

I modified your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/P4b8H/5/

Answer (score 0):

Place the image in a box. Append the div to the same box. Then apply the hover event, well, again to that same box. Take a look at the altered fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/P4b8H/4/

Comment: But this would be on any website. So i can't make it so that there is a div wrapping it all the time.

Comment: Hide wrapper when you leave wrapper, not when you leave image. http://jsfiddle.net/P4b8H/6/

Comment: damiand figured it out too, before me I guess. I'll vote his answer up.